# Does adobe AIR support jQuery?

Tags: jquery, air

Anyone knows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, see:

- [Learn Adobe AIR, Part I: Build A Note Storage App](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/learn-adobe-air-part-1)